# Unable to launch rails due to "'executable-hooks (= 1.6.0)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Have had this error for a couple of weeks now and keep giving up trying to solve it, forget about it and then rediscover it. The cycle of pain has been killing me.

```
/Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:231:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'executable-hooks (= 1.6.0)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:283:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `each'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_by'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `with_index'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_dependencies'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `block in sort_dependencies'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in `sort_dependencies'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:165:in `initial_state'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:106:in `start_resolution'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:64:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:188:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:396:in `resolve'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:408:in `resolve_current'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:311:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:309:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:309:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /Users/Samudabamu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I've tried completely purging ruby version manager(rvm), reinstalling bundler, xcode, openssl amongst other things. Could this potentially be a $PATH problem? Really clutching at straws here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `gem install executable-hooks`?

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just letting the community know that I never resolved this. I ended up doing a fresh install of OSX to circumnavigate the problem, which is definitely NOT the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

My expedient workaround for this is to uninstall executable-hooks (good enough for my use case, but may introduce other issues — use with caution):

```bash
% solargraph -v

# ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem solargraph (>= 0.a) with executable solargraph (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
# ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `activate_bin_path'
# ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/solargraph:25:in `<main>'
# ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
# ~/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.0.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

```bash
% gem uninstall executable hooks
```

```bash
% solargraph -v
# 0.48.0
```